# Search functionality issues using rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to implement a search functionality.

In my component:

```
this.newsArticles$ = this.searchKeyChanged$.pipe(
   debounceTime(200),
   distinctUntilChanged(),
   switchMap(searchKey =>
     searchKey?.length > 0 ? this.newsService.getNewsArticlesByKey(searchKey) : this.newsService.getNewsArticles()
      ))
```

In my service:

```
getNewsArticles(): Observable<NewsArticle[]> { /// some http request to get all the news articles}

getNewsArticlesByKey(searchKey: string): Observable<NewsArticle[]> {
    return this.getNewsArticles().pipe(map(articles => filterArticlesByKey(articles, searchKey)));
  }
```

When the searchKey changes, the switchMap is not triggered somehow.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Before your `switchMap`, try `tap(console.log)` to see what's being passed in?

Comment: i guess you are missing `return` in switchMap.
`return  searchKey?.length > 0 ? this.newsService.getNewsArticlesByKey(searchKey) : this.newsService.getNewsArticles()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you subscribed to the newsArticles$ observable? Http requests are "Cold" Observables. This means they are lazily executed and so the request is only actually made when there is a subscriber. You should also be aware that this means if you subscribe to this Observable twice then you will get two HTTP requests unless you use something like the share operator.

Answer (score 0):

I see two main issues that might occur during the flow:

1. Your `distinctUntilChanged` might block the emissions. Add a `tap(v => console.log(v))` before `distinctUntilChanged`.
2. Your `getNewsArticles()` or `getNewsArticlesByKey(key: string)` might return an error and result the stream cancellation. In this case, think of changing `switchMap` to `flatMap` or `concatMap` - they don't have the cancelling effect.
   More info here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap